# How to remove the text field when using a file upload

Tags: javascript, html

How to remove the text field when using a file upload

Here is the code which i have used.

```
<tr><td align="center" width="10%">06. </td><td width="30%" align="right">Upload group photo : </td><td width="30%" align="left" ><INPUT type="file" /></td></tr>
```

If am using the above code its displaying a text box together with the file upload button

Comment: Is the code invisible or only i can't see it?

Comment: where is the code? you may have to edit your question.

Comment: What he means is how do you remove the input area where the file name goes. How to have a custom file input area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="button" value="Browse.."
onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('imagefile').click();">
<input id="imagefile" type="file" style='visibility: hidden;' name="img" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a possible answer on another website. This is the link:

[HTML file upload without the text box](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/465052-html-file-upload-without-the-text-box/)

The trick is to use a `<div>` with a transparent `<input>`. You can design the `<div>` as you want it, but when you click the `<div>` you actually click the `<input>`. Hope it helps.